# How do I back up Mozilla Thunderbird emails when upgrading to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I back up Thunderbird emails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114015/how-do-i-back-up-thunderbird-emails)

I currently use 10.04LTS and want to upgrade to 12.04LTS. How do I get my inbox and sent messages backed up so that I can re-open them in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to backup the Thunderbird profile.

Open your Homoe directory, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files and folder, look for ".thunderbird" folder and save it somewhere. After upgrade just put it back there.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Very much appreciated!