# Thunderbird 16 and Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I have just upgraded from Thunderbird 15 to 16 and then found that Lightning 1.7 is not compatible with Thunderbird 16, leaving me without a calendar.

What are my options?

Should I try and go back to Thunderbird 15 or is there someway of finding a version of Lightning that is compatible with Thunderbird 16?

I need to have a working calender and have been happily using Lightning for many years.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 32-bit if that is any help

Answer (score 2):

Lightning 1.8 has been uploaded

[https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next)

[ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-next) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Lightning 1.8 should also be pushed out with Thunderbird 16 when it is released to the main archive (with the exception of 10.04 which will need to go to lucid-backports and might lag behind a day or 2)

Comment: why can't you add this from add-on's?

Comment: addons are either 32 bit only or platform independent, lightning is an architecture specific addon which means that it can't properly be supported through addons.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Thunderbird Add-on '[Disable Add-on Compatibility Checks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/checkcompatibility/)' to bypass this problem.

This is a workaround though, realize that once you do this you may introduce bugs with Thunderbird or your Add-ons.

It's a good idea to keep a backup of your Thunderbird profile to restore from if anything breaks or fails. [Here's how](https://askubuntu.com/q/114015/12864).

Comment: Lightning is a binary addon, so the compatibility checks shouldn't make any difference