# How can I use my backup of Thunderbird

Tags: backup, thunderbird

I read "How do I back up Thunderbird emails?" from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114015/how-do-i-back-up-thunderbird-emails).

How can I use it again when the account will be deleted from Thunderbird or change the operating system?

Comment: To restore (or move your email settings & mails to another system, newly installed etc) simply copy the whole backed-up `.thunderbird`  folder to `~/`. Even extensions like Lightning will be available again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder `~/.thunderbird` includes everything you need. It includes emails, accounts, settings, (email-) passwords etc. If you simply backup the folder regularly, you can simply copy it back to your newly installed system, into `~/` (which is your home directory, `/home/yourname`).

Even the installed extensions, add-ons etc. will be available instantly in most cases, with no other action but simply copying back the (whole) backed-up `~/.thunderbird` -folder into `~/`.

Couldn't be easier :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am unable to access my mails. Please tell how i can access my mail?

Comment: @puneetDixit Not sure what you mean, if you copy `~/.thunderbird` from old to new install, *all* your mails will be available. Just run thunderbird and it will be like you used to use it.

Comment: Oh sorry! it was my fault.  It is simple but i think it has a security risk that if anyone can find my backup folder he can access my emails while in outlook he must have the password of the mail.

Comment: @puneetDixit Well, yes, but the password is in the local folder. Backups should be in a more or less secure location (of course : ) ) depending on how sensitive the information is.

Comment: I found my answer for which i am looking. Thanks very much Mr. Jacob.